# Give page transition each category changed with jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

How to give page transition, with each category name and qty, I mean when I click office category, it will show an popup overlay with that name caption also qty while loading, don't mind for the category name, and qty, it will do on PHP, I just need each transition will showing that overlay effect.

[image]

[image]

```
    <div class="desk-08 tab-08 mob-hide prod-nav">
            <h2 id="prod-title">Products</h2>
            <div id="shop-categories-with-links-and-totals">
            <ul class="products-nav-list">
             <li class="md-top-product-category-link "><a href="/products" cat_title="All Products" class="shop-cat-link" ajaxload="ajaxyes" slug="products" num_products="138" home_url ="/"><span class="nav-all-desktop">All</span><span class="nav-all-mobile">Products</span><span class="md-top-product-category-count"><span>138</span></span></a></li>
             <li class="md-top-product-category-link"><a href="/product-category/office/" cat_title="Office" class="shop-cat-link" ajaxload="ajaxno" slug="office" num_products="27" home_url ="h/">Office<span class="md-top-product-category-count"><span>27</span></span></a></li>
             <li class="md-top-product-category-link"><a href="/books-magazines/" cat_title="Books &amp; Magazines" class="shop-cat-link" ajaxload="ajaxno" slug="books-magazines" num_products="39" home_url ="/">Books &amp; Magazines<span class="md-top-product-category-count"><span>39</span></span></a></li>                  
             <li class="md-top-product-category-link"><a href="/product-category/home/" cat_title="Home" class="shop-cat-link" ajaxload="ajaxno" slug="home" num_products="45" home_url ="/">Home<span class="md-top-product-category-count"><span>45</span></span></a></li>
             <li class="md-top-product-category-link"><a href="/product-category/children/" cat_title="Children" class="shop-cat-link" ajaxload="ajaxno" slug="children" num_products="23" home_url ="/">Children<span class="md-top-product-category-count"><span>23</span></span></a></li>
             <li class="md-top-product-category-link"><a href="/product-category/outdoor/" cat_title="Outdoor" class="shop-cat-link" ajaxload="ajaxno" slug="outdoor" num_products="10" home_url ="/">Outdoor<span class="md-top-product-category-count"><span>10</span></span></a></li>
             <li class="nav-search-link"><a href="ajax-search" class="search" data-fancybox-type="iframe">Search</a></li>
             <li class="nav-index-link"><a href="index/">Index</a></li></ul></div>          
    </div>  

ul.products-nav-list li {
    margin-right: 12px;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
}
.navigation ul li {
    color: #8A8A8A;
    border-top: 0px none;
    display: inline-block;
}
.navigation ul li a {
    padding: 0px;
    outline: 0px none;
}
.navigation ul li a {
    line-height: 51px;
    height: 50px;
}
.navigation ul li a {
    color: #8A8A8A;
    padding: 0px;
    display: block;
    line-height: 34px;
    height: 32px;
}
.navigation ul li a .md-top-product-category-count {
    display: inline;
}
.navigation ul li a .md-top-product-category-count {
    display: none;
    color: #8A8A8A;
    vertical-align: super;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably include a div in the structure as the overlay and then toggle the class.

```
div#overlay {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    display:none;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);
    -webkit-transition: background-color 600ms ease;
    -moz-transition: background-color 600ms ease;
    -ms-transition: background-color 600ms ease;
    transition: background-color 600ms ease;
}

div#overlay.active {
    display:block;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.8);
}
```

Then you could use .toggleClass on click

```
$('a').on('click', function(e){
  $('div#overlay').toggleClass('active');
});
```

Note, because of `display:none;` this method wont fade back.  It will simply disappear.